# How can I delete private information in a bug report?

Tags: security, launchpad, bug-reporting

If I report a bug to launchpad using `ubuntu-bug` it usually adds a bunch of files about my system to the bug, it also adds a automatic generated bug summary to my bug report text. Both the summary and the attached files may potentially contain private imformation such as my user name, host name etc. I didn't find any option to edit the summary or the files. I just know how to delete the attachement.

So, how can I delete or change the private information in the summary and attached files?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any easy way of removing any private information from crash logs, but your files should be uploaded privately as it's well explained in [Ubuntu Wiki at Triage](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Triage):

> **Apport reports**
>
> A considerable number of bugs reported by Apport concern program
>   crashes which are reported semi-automatically and get pre-processed
>   automatically by bots in the Canonical data center. These bots try to
>   generate a fully symbolic stack trace and check for duplicates.
>
> In Feisty and early Gutsy, those bugs were public, so that everyone
>   could see them. However, this created a privacy problem since core
>   dumps and stack traces could potentially contain sensitive
>   information. Also, crash reports generate a lot of bug mail noise.
>   With the automatic duplicate checking, a fair amount of the reported
>   bugs are completely irrelevant for triagers.
>
> Since Gutsy, these problems have been mitigated: bugs are filed with
>   the "private" flag enabled, i. e. only the reporter and subscribers
>   can see it. The reprocessing bots will subscribe the ubuntu-bugcontrol
>   team, but without sending bug email to the team members.
>
> Thus crash bugs differ from other bugs in two important aspects: they
>   need to be checked for sensitive data, and there will not be any
>   initial bug mail for them until they become public. Triagers should
>   check the following things:
>
> - If the crash still has a CoreDump.gz attachment, then it was not    possible to automatically get a fully symbolic stack trace and check
>     for duplicates. In this case, the bug will be tagged with apport-failed-retrace.
> - If the stack trace looks good enough, the    CoreDump.gz attachment should be removed with the (edit) link in the    attachment box. If
>     the retrace failed completely, mark the bug as    'Invalid' and ask
>     the reporter to refile the bug if the crash can be    reproduced.
>     Never mark a bug containing a Coredump.gz attachment as    public. If
>     there is no Stacktrace.txt (retraced) attachment, then the    most
>     probable reason is that the CoreDump.gz attachment is broken.
>     Please check with Martin Pitt (pitti in IRC, martin.pitt@ubuntu.com)
>     about the reason since he can look into log files.
> - Check if any of    stacktrace attachments (original stacktraces, Stacktrace.txt    (retraced) and ThreadStacktrace.txt (retraced)) have
>     anything that    looks like sensitive data passed as function
>     arguments. Examples are    passwords, things that look like bank
>     account numbers, CSS keys, user    names, server names, etc. If you
>     don't find anything, you may mark    the bug as public ("This report
>     is public/private" in the top right    of the bug report). This is not
>     required though, it is fine to keep    the bug private throughout its
>     lifetime. Except for those privacy    issues, crash reports should be
>     handled like normal bugs in terms of    duplicate searching/marking,
>     upstream forwarding, etc.

If you don't want to send any private information, try to report the bug manually, without using `ubuntu-bug` tool.

---

**More advanced method**

Alternatively report the bug by logged in by different user or from the virtual machine.

Or scan the files before sending (if you know where they are) by `cat`/`gzcat` and `strings`, e.g.

```
find /var/log -name \*.gz -exec sh -c "gzcat '{}'|strings"  \;
find /var/log -name \*.log -exec sh -c "cat '{}'|strings"  \;
```

Where /var/log is the dir with compressed crash logs, use *.gz for compressed files, use *.log or whatever for non-compressed files. The command will print every string which is stored in these logs. You may also grep them for looking specific private data, if you know what you're looking for.

If you know which file it's, then just edit it or replace it by sed, e.g.

```
sed -i'.bak' s/private/XXXXXXX/g name_of_the_file.log
```

See also:

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)